# Can you please help me with this code?

Tags: java, android, webview

The problem: When I Type a ID and press the button, it will not load the ID's webpage...

"a url" is the website page i'm trying to create, (Hidden for number of reasons)

It should be working, it loads the first site, but when I try to call for the IDs, the WebView does not change... Can someone please help me? -Thanks, JG1

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    try {
        String url = "a url";
        wv.loadUrl(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String lid = "0";

    //Clicking button changes to the color

}

final EditText idbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final Button idbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idbtn);
final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

public void onClick(View v) {
    idbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String lid = idbox.getText().toString();
            if (lid == "1") {
                wv.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
                try {
                    String urla = "a url";
                    wv.loadUrl(urla);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (lid == "2") {
                wv.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
                try {
                    String urlb = "a url";
                    wv.loadUrl(urlb);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (lid == "3") {
                wv.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
                try {
                    String urlc = "a url";
                    wv.loadUrl(urlc);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `lid=="1"` - you cannot compare `String` contents using the equality operator.  `==` tests whether two objects are the same object.  Use `equals()` instead (and consider doing some basic Java tutorials).  Through string interning, `lid=="1"` **might** be true sometimes, but you have no control over that.  BTW, if you learned how to use the debugger, you would find that in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, You had been called the same URL value like ("a url"). If yes, try to load different URLs in the web view.

If not, do the following changes in your code,

- Put break points to debug your code where you get EditText value.

  String lid = idbox.getText().toString(); //check lid is **null** or **not**
- Change the if condition like this,

  if(lid.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
     {
     //task for rendering web page
     }
- Check your custom view client class.

Comment: They are all different urls, Is there a reason that the first "a url" URL is loading?

Comment: Yes, because it is outside the `if` statements, which will never work as I said in my comment.

Comment: Did you get the edit text values here (String lid = idbox.getText().toString();) If lid value is null you can't load web pages dynamically based on your EditText Value.

Comment: **Is there a reason that the first "a url" URL is loading? ** Because your ("a url") web page loading code is inside the onCreate() method, So the first url is loading nicely, you did write other three loading urls code outside the onCreate() method, so they did not render the web pages. Moreover you did not declare, initialize and define the variables and function(onClick(View v)) properly, So that Runtime error occurred. I did add updated code below.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, **You written onClick() method definition is wrongly!**

I confused because,

- Have you been adding the onclick(**android:onClick="onClick"**) function for button in xml.

  In spite of I did some bit changes in your code,

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/urlValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/urlBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        android:text="load"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText getUrlValue;
private Button loadUrl;
private WebView webView;
String loadId = "";
String URL_ONE = "a_url";
String URL_TWO = "b_url";
String URL_THREE = "c_url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    getUrlValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlValue);
    loadUrl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.urlBtn);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    
    //initial view for webView
    getUrlValue.setText("1"); //here web page will load first url= "a url"
    
    webView.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
    
    //onClick Event for load url button
    loadUrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        
            loadId = getUrlValue.getText().toString();
            if(loadId.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                try{
                    
                    webView.loadUrl(URL_ONE);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            else if(loadId.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                try{
                    webView.loadUrl(URL_TWO);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                
            }
            else{
                try{
                    webView.loadUrl(URL_THREE);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
           }
        }
       });
        
    }
 }
```

- remember to add internet permission in the manifest xml file.